# Is it acceptable to use htmlentities() before passing data to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm retrieving some data from a database (all using prepared statements) into an array, then outputting that data as JSON

I then process the data with JavaScript and display it on the web page (as a list).

Is it acceptable to run `htmlentities($data, ENT_QUOTES)` on the DB results as I'm adding them to the array before converting it to JSON and outputting it? Will I run into any issues doing so?

Or should I do all of this using JavaScript? Usually, I would always use `htmlentities()` before outputting data directly onto a web page, but I'm not sure if it's OK to do so when I'm using JSON and parsing the data with JavaScript. As far as I'm aware there's no similar function in JS either.

The database has text fields and could contain anything (including things which will break a web page)

Edit: Example code (PHP side)

```
$DB_results = array('Test', '123', '<b>hello</b>', 'B&$B%');

echo json_encode($DB_results);
```

JS code:

```
var db_results = JSON.parse(this.responseText); // this is from an AJAX query

var dbr_length = db_results.length;

for (var i = 0; var i < dbr_length; i++)
{
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(years[i]));
    document.getElementById('mylist').appendChild(li);   
}
```

Should I amend the PHP code to the following (keep in mind `htmlentities()` would be added while adding the data to the array

```
$DB_results = array(
    htmlentities('Test', ENT_QUOTES),
    htmlentities('123', ENT_QUOTES),
    htmlentities('<b>hello</b>', ENT_QUOTES),
    htmlentities('B&$B%', ENT_QUOTES)
);

echo json_encode($DB_results);
```

Comment: Everything about this question hinges on "_I then process the data with JavaScript and display it on the web page (as a list)._", but you haven't shown any code. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @jsejcksn OK, I've added some code now

Comment: If you would know why `htmlentites` is used - then you, probabliy, wouldn't have such question... Htmlentites is used to prevent user from XSS attack, so you have to put inside htmlentities only that data that will be displayed to a client on the website. Since you don't output the reponseText itself - you should not add htmlentities to it. But you should add to each other element, that you will output later. You can do it in javascript or php - it does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've answered the question yourself, but if you want more confidence, you can reference the MDN docs for [`Document.createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode):

> Creates a new [`Text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) node. **This method can be used to escape HTML characters.**

And the code in your question (slightly modified in order to execute without `ReferenceError`s):

```js
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('ul')).id = 'mylist';

const json = `["Test","123","<b>hello</b>","B&$B%"]`;
const dbResults = JSON.parse(json);

for (const str of dbResults) {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
  document.getElementById('mylist').appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So `.createTextNode()` will do the job of `htmlentities()` and make that unnecessary, because it's literally converting everything to text? And if I were to use `.innerHTML()` I would then need to escape HTML characters?

Comment: @cantsay Yes. You might also want to keep an eye on the [HTML Sanitizer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Sanitizer_API).